# Applying Django migrations in a non-interactive environment

Tags: python, django, heroku, database-migration

I've renamed some models in Django and created the migrations using `python manage.py makemigrations`.

When using `python manage.py migrate`, I get prompted with the following message

> Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
>   be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
>   If you're unsure, answer 'no'.
>
> Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:

On my local machine, I can simply type 'yes'. However, 
my application is deployed on Heroku and I have configured migrations to run automatically when the application is built. I achieve this using a `post_compile` file that looks like this:

```
# Run Django migrations
./manage.py migrate

# Compress static assets
./manage.py compress
```

Will the migration simply fail to complete as a consequence of not being in an interactive shell (and therefore not being able to answer 'yes' to this question)? If so, how can this problem be avoided?

Comment: One option is running `bash` under heroku and then migrating under its interactive environment: `heroku run your-app-name bash`

Comment: @kaveh Thanks for the tip. I was hoping to keep it all automated but that would be a good fallback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `--noinput` command line argument of `migrate` command:

```
./manage.py migrate --noinput
```

This would suppress the prompt, but will **not** delete stale content types (ie. it works as if you answered `No` at the prompt). See [Django ticket #25036](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25036) .

Another alternative would be to use the Unix command `yes` (I am not sure if it is enabled on Heroku by default though):

```
yes "yes" | ./manage.py migrate
```